# How can I find where an image texture is being used?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image

I was scrolling the images my file uses, and I noticed an image, that I don't remember, is used in my file. I tried going though all the materials and looking at nodes to find which one uses this image texture. It doesn't have the 0 before its name, so I know it's being used somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Is there a way I can figure out which material is using this image texture?

Comment: Do you remember the image name? If you know the image name: img.png, you can find where the image used via a script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Amaranth Toolset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/addons/interface/amaranth.html#amaranth-toolset) that is bundled with Blender. Among other useful tools, you can use it to list the users of an image in your file. It will tell you which material and object is using the image.

Find this in the *scene properties* under *Scene Debug*:

[image]

Comment: So this powerful add-on is disabled in default, we need to turn in on.